# Wamp MYSQL can't start

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have a problem with my WAMPServer since few weeks.
MySQL service can't start and I don't have the solution...

I've tried to uninstall and install Wamp and change the MySQL who is not used, but he can't start, why ?

Error is :

```
2021-05-07T09:45:13.549741Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.21\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 22580
2021-05-07T09:45:13.731100Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-05-07T09:45:14.624458Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-05-07T09:45:14.962879Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010262] [Server] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.


2021-05-07T09:45:14.963609Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010257] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-05-07T09:45:14.964258Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-05-07T09:45:16.076956Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.21\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Log claims that some service/application uses needed port 3306. Check what process uses. it.

Comment: Look like you may have 2 MySQL instances on this system. Something else has definitely grabbed port 3306 before you get to start the WAMPServer version of MySQL it would appear

Comment: What version of WAMPServer are you running? Can you do a `Right click -> Tools -> Create WAMPServer configuration report` it will create a file called `wampConfReport.txt` in the `C:\wamp64` folder. Can you then show us that please

Comment: @RiggsFolly Here the link to my logs : https://pastebin.com/146tsegZ

Comment: I've already tried to change the MySQL port but the problem is again there... It's very strange!

Comment: I dont suppose you are running both the 32bit WAMPServer and the 64bit WAMPServer at the same time??

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, only 64 bits and one time

Answer (score 0):

Seems both port 3306(MySQL) and 3307(mariaDB) are in use by some other process.

Start a command window using "Run as Administrator" then do

```
netstat -anob | findstr "3306"
```

that should show you what is using port 3306, the output is like this

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       19768
  TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       19768
```

The last number `19768` is a PID and you then do the following to find the program running on that PID

```
tasklist|findstr "19768"
```

> Of course the PID you will see will not be the same number as mine, once you know what program is using port 3306 you can decide what to do about it!

If you are not sure comment under here and we can work it out between us

**Final Suggestion**

The only "trick" that comes to mind would be to perform a network "clean-up".
In a "as administrator" command window, type the following commands:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ip reset reset.log
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
```

This resets the IP configuration.
At the end, the system must be restarted.

Comment: Okay, when I'm trying to write your first command, there is no result in Administrator.

Comment: Are you sure you started the command windows using the "Run as Administrator" option....[See a how to here](https://superuser.com/a/968225/220717)

Comment: Yes, Run as Administrator.. but no result. Output is empty.

Comment: try `netstat -anob | findstr ":33"`

Comment: Yes, there are two TCP and UDP for the port 3389. It's the RDP port if I know...

Comment: Well that suggests that nothing is using port 3306. I dont suppose you have changed BOTH MySQL and mariaDB to both run on port 3306 have you?

Comment: MySQL use 3306 and mariaDB 3307, why he not working? :/

Comment: Is this a Home PC or an office one?

Comment: It's a home PC .

Comment: Did you ever install a MySQL or mariaDB before you started using WAMPServer

Comment: No, I've only install WAMPServer with his services. Normally.

Comment: Just added my last gasp attempt at a solution